# Display "no map data for this scale" instead of changing zoom when switching map type

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

In google maps API v3, I'm creating my own custom map types by calling

```
map.mapTypes.set('my map', new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: ...
    minZoom: 12,
    maxZoom: 20,
    ...
}));
```

The layers have of course limited zoom range (12-20 in this example). Now the problem is the default behaviour of google maps. When I see map in scale 7 for example and switch to my map, **the map automatically zooms in to zoom 12**.

Instead, when I am in zoom 7 and switch to my map, **I would like to see tiles with text "No map data in this scale, please zoom in".**

- Is there some standard option / way how to do this within API v3?
- Is there some commonly used solution to this problem?
- If not, what would be the easiest way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ahisha, what you mean with "my map function"? And how does getZoom solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid `minZoom` and `maxZoom` options and try something like this:

```
map.mapTypes.set('my map', new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function( position, zoom ){
        if( zoom >= 12 && zoom <= 20 ){
            return "http://example.com/tileservice?x="+position.x+"&y="+position.y+"&zoom="+zoom;
        }else{
            return "http://example.com/no_map_data_in_this_scale_please_zoom_in.png";
        }
    },
    ...
}));
```

Comment: Good idea! It would of course be better if this is already somehow solved by google, just passing it message as text in my language, without need for creating my own tiles. But If there is no such solution, I'd go this way.

Comment: @Tomas `ImageMapType` is intended for working only with images. So if you want to work with images and text, probably you need to right your own `MapType` and hope https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base?hl=ru link will help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however it seems this is not the way to go if one is looking for simple, not-complicated solutions :-) The custom tile images win at the moment.